# WordCloud 'local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, wordcloud2

I am a newbie with python and I am trying to define a function that will return a WordCloud of job tokens from a specific city_state. The code runs independently, but as a function, I can't figure out how to fix the error. I am getting a

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comment_words' referenced before assignment

```
def jobs_wordcloud(city_state):
cols = ['base_tokens']
for val in jobs_df.loc[jobs_df['city_state'] == city_state, cols]:
    val = str(val)
    tokens = word_tokenize(val)
    tokens = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z 0-9]', '', val)
    tokens = tokens.lower().split()
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
    tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower().strip()) for w in tokens]
    comment_words += " ".join(tokens) + " "

wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,
    background_color = 'white',
    stopwords = stop_words,
    min_font_size = 10).generate(comment_words)
  
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10), facecolor = None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()

return plt.show()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8df36e8cfe41> in <module>()
----> 1 jobs_wordcloud('San Francisco, CA')

<ipython-input-30-1a42912ec34f> in jobs_wordcloud(city_state)
     11         tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
     12         tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower().strip()) for w in tokens]
---> 13         comment_words += " ".join(tokens) + " "
     14 
     15     wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comment_words' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your posted code does not run.  You did not supply the full error message.

Comment: @Prune UnboundLocalError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8df36e8cfe41> in <module>()
----> 1 jobs_wordcloud('San Francisco, CA')

<ipython-input-30-1a42912ec34f> in jobs_wordcloud(city_state)
     11         tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
     12         tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower().strip()) for w in tokens]
---> 13         comment_words += " ".join(tokens) + " "
     14 
     15     wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comment_words' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Prune that is the full error I get when I try to run the function above.

Comment: ... and there is the problem.  You're trying to add something to a non-existent value.  The first time you hit that statement, `comment_words` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `comment_words = ''` before you begin the loop in the `jobs_wordcloud` function.

Since you are effectively doing `comment_words = comment_words + SOMETHING`, python needs to know what is the value of comment_words.